# Async gRCP server with maximum_concurrent_rpcs limitation raises an exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, grpc, grpc-python

I tried to implement gRPC server with [gRPC AsyncIO API](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html). I used this [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/async_greeter_server.py) as a sample and tried to define maximum_concurrent_rpcs limitation on server as described in source code documentation in [gRPC AsyncIO server source code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/58aa564385b468b6a95cafe7400def2239486a17/src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_server.py#L175).
Here is my implementation:

```
import asyncio
from grpc.experimental import aio

import helloworld_pb2
import helloworld_pb2_grpc


class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):

    async def SayHello(self, request, context):
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)


async def serve():
    server = aio.server(maximum_concurrent_rpcs = 10)
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)
    listen_addr = '[::]:50051'
    server.add_insecure_port(listen_addr)
    logging.info("Starting server on %s", listen_addr)
    await server.start()
    await server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(serve())
```

But it raises the following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'Server' object has no attribute '_server'
```

My question is, how is it possible to define gRPC AsyncIO server with maximum_concurrent_rpcs limitation.

Note that `helloworld_pb2` and `helloworld_pb2_grpc` are available in this [repositroy](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld)

Answer (score 1):

Because of this import, it seems you didn't use the latest version.

```
from grpc.experimental import aio
```

Comment: I get NotImplementedError in both variants when I specify maximum_concurrent_rpcs

```self._server = cygrpc.AioServer(
  File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/_cygrpc/aio/server.pyx.pxi", line 820, in grpc._cython.cygrpc.AioServer.__init__
NotImplementedError```

Comment: Which versions?

Comment: Latest pypi version of grpc